# Regex to add a new line break after each bracket

Tags: javascript, regex, newline

I have tried using replace with regex `(/\([(]\)/g,'\1\n')` but its not helping. Any help?

Comment: is this JavaScript?

Comment: In JS, you should use something like `.replace(/[()]/g,'$&\n')` (to add newline after `(` or `)`, easily expandable by adding more symbols into the `[...]` character class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless what the language is, a round bracket matching pattern is either `\(` or `[(]`. If you need to use a whole match value in the replacement, there are `$&` or `$0` backreferences.

Thus, search for `/[(]/g` (you may add more chars into the character class, like `[()\][]`...) and replace with `"$&\n"` (or `"$0\n"`).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UXvQc4/1).

A JS demo:

```js
var regex = /[(]/g;
var str = "before(after and before 1(after1";
var subst = "$&\n";
var result = str.replace(regex, subst);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: If you have any feedback, feel free to drop comments here.

Comment: Thanks got it solved. However only "$&\n" added a new line while "$0\n" rather replaced the bracket.

Comment: So, it is JS and you are using IE, right? Note that I had to use `$0` at regex101 since for some reason the `$&` backreference is not recognized for the JS regex flavor. It is a bug. I added a snippet here.

Comment: Yes it is JS :)